# Item of a list can not be read by if-statement. What have I done wrong?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

Hey guys I need your help! For a school projekt I want to create a flashcard programm in python. I imported a csv-data which include questions and answers and put them in two seperate lists.

```
with open("List_Questions_Answers.csv", "r") as data:

    Q = []
    A = []

    next(data)

    for line in data:
        q, a = line.split(",")
        Q.append(q)
        A.append(a)
```

Then I want to ask the user the questions and give feedback if it is right or wrong. But there is the problem: I alway get a "wrong" as feedback even if it is the right answer. When I change the list item with e.g. "1" the program works. I am really frustrated, can someone help me?

```
guess = input(f"{Q[1]}")
if guess == A[1]:
    print("Right")
else:
    print("Wrong", A[1])
```

Comment: Could you post a few lines of the CSV file? What is `A[1]` and what is the value of `guess`?

Comment: Did you mean: `q, a = line.strip().split(",")`? Your answers may have a line feed, so they will never match the user input.

Comment: what is the purpose of next(data) ? , can you print Q and A list for us ? so that we have an idea

Comment: shouldnt be something like 'data = data.read' present before the next(data) ?

Comment: @pippo1980 No, `next(data)` skips to the next line (`data` is an iterator containing the liens of the file).

Comment: @pippo1980: the `next(data)` discards the header. And the `for line in data:` just reads each subsequent line of the file. All seems correct there in the code from the OP.

Comment: using : q, a = line.strip().split(",") and gg = randint(0 , len(Q)+1)
guess = input(f"{Q[gg]}")
if guess == A[gg]:
    print("Right")
else:
    print("Wrong", A[gg]) works

Comment: this is my csv file:

Comment: Question,Answer
What is the highest mountain in the world?,Mount Everest
How many months has a year?,12
In which month do we celebrate christmas?,December

Comment: So with next(data) I want to skip the first line (Question,Answer)

Comment: to me it works, can you add the code that doesnt work ?

Comment: sorry gg = randint(0 , len(Q)+1) should be gg = randint(0 , len(Q)-1)

Comment: Oh I forgot to import random. Now it works. Thank you very much!!!